# SQL/PHP Multiple querys

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't understand this because I'm just getting into query's and php.

I'm trying to get the user's ID from the database and set that equal to a different users `friendreq` column.

*Don't worry about me not escaping properly, this is only a test so I can practice!* Thank you! (Although I'm not sure what escaping is, I'm going to do my research!)

```
$usernameID = "SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username'";
$sql = "UPDATE Users SET FriendReq = $usernameID WHERE Username =  '$usernamebeingreq'";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($con, $usernameID, $sql);

if(!$result)
{ 
    echo 'Failed';
} 
else
{
    echo 'Friend added!';
}
```

Comment: You should not only be escaping user inserted parts of the query, but rather use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). They're the safest way of handling a query in PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll make sure to look through that, any advice on the multi query?

Comment: If you're just practicing why bother with this multi_query thing? Just do the queries one after the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) of `mysqli_multi_query` your two queries need to be concatenated with a semicolon. You're passing each query as its own parameter.

Use the following instead:

```
$result = mysqli_multi_query($con, $usernameID . "; " . $sql);
```

This will concatenate your two queries, so that it's the following:

```
SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username'; UPDATE Users SET FriendReq = $usernameID WHERE Username =  '$usernamebeingreq'
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you for all the tips, I tried to concatenate them but without the semi-colin in the middle! Thanks!!

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Why shouldn't it? This is what the PHP reference told us.

Comment: because `$sql` becomes `"UPDATE Users SET FriendReq = SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' WHERE Username =  '$usernamebeingreq'"`  
and `$usernameID . "; " . $sql` becomes `"SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username'; UPDATE Users SET FriendReq = SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' WHERE Username =  '$usernamebeingreq'"` which is not what you want.

Comment: It's two queries, not one. The `;` splits them and `mysqli_multi_query` executes them one after another.